# frustration with command line argument = $1 and awk column 1 = $1

Tags: unix

I am trying to read through the first line of a file and find a column that is specified in the command line.  For example: `command <column> <textfile>` so column is `$1` and textfile `$2`.

I am writing an awk command to split the file-columns into an array and then a for loop to check when the array element matches the column argument.  Here is the code:

```
awk 'NR == 1 {split ( $0,titles ); for ( i=1 ; titles[i] != "$1" ; i++ ) ; FS = " "} NR > 1 {print $i }' file
```

I want the `$1` to refer to the first command line argument NOT the first column that awk sees.  **How do I get the column argument in the for loop?** I thought I could make a variable for `$1` and pass it to `awk` but that didn't work or I did it wrong - either/or.  I have been looking up stuff about this for hours.  I might be missing something obvious or dumb but its gotten to the point where I really just need to know how to do this.  Also in my search for the answer I read stuff about `ARGV[]`.  I thought `ARGV[1] == $1` but apparently not so what does the `ARGV` array refer to?  Thanks for any help you can offer.

*(Note: just to help with any confusion file is an edited version of textfile known as $2)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk -v column="$1" 'NR == 1 { ... } NR > 1 { ... }' "$2"
```

Inside the `awk` script, you can refer to the value passed to the shell script as `$1` by the name `column` (the `-v` flag presets `awk` variables).

I don't quite understand your explanation of what you're up to, but I think that I'd use:

```
awk -v column="$1" '
    NR == 1 { for (i = 1; $i != column && i <= NF; i++) ; }
    NR >  1 { print $i }' \
    "$2"
```

`awk` splits lines up into fields all on its own; you don't need the `split` function; nor do you need to play with `FS`.

Comment: Thank you you are right. I tried that but I guess I had something written wrong. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

In awk, the first command line argument is `ARGV[1]`, while `$1` is the first word on the current line. They're two entirely different things.

For example:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN { print "ARGV[1] =", ARGV[1] }' foo bar
ARGV[1] = foo
```